# Prove that if Y is a closed and bounded subset of $R^{N}$ then Y is complete and totally bounded (pre-compact).

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Prove that if Y is a closed and bounded subset of $R^{N}$ then Y is complete and totally bounded (pre-compact).

I was able to prove that Y is complete by showing that a Cauchy sequence in Y has a converging subsequence in Y and using that to say that the sequence also converges to the same value in Y. However, I am not sure about the totally bounded part. By definition, I am supposed to show that Y has a finite cover where the diameter of the sets in the cover can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: What metric are you using for the product? It will affect the details of the argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The problem does not say, but based on the statement of the theorem in my lecture notes, the Euclidean metric $d_{E}$.

Comment: I think that I was operating with a misconception: is this the infinite product $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, or is it $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$? I took it to be the former.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Should be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is closed and bounded, by the Heine-Borel theorem, it is compact.

Then since $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a finite dimensional vector space, a compact set is sequentially compact, so every sequence in $Y$ has a convergent subsequence and limits are unique, so every convergent sequence converges to an element of the set. $Y$ is complete since every convergent sequence converges to an element of the set, so every cauchy sequence converges.

Since $Y$ is bounded, take the $\delta >0$ for which $Y \subset B_{\delta}(0) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^N: ||x|| < \delta \}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  Imagine the $k-$cell that encloses $Y$ as in the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem with diameter $\delta+1$.  Subdivide the $k-$cell so that the volume of each element of the cell is less than $\varepsilon$. So in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you need $k$ large enough that $ \frac{(1+\delta)^2}{2^k}< \varepsilon$, and in $\mathbb{R}^N$, it would be something like $ \frac{(1+\delta)^N}{2^{k}} < \varepsilon$; scan the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem to get the details, I have had too much vodka to remember it exactly and I don't have a pad of paper to sketch it out.

This coronavirus thing is killing me.